Convergence of recursively defined functions over finite sets
I was trying to model a situation and stumbled upon the following. It uses a function $f$ that has itself as a part of its definition. I am not sure how to deal with it and thought looking into recursion might help, although I am not sure.
I have a finite set $A$. Let $F = \{f_1, ...., f_m\}$ be a set of functions from $A$ to $\{1, ...., |A|\}$. There is also a function $R$ from $F$ to $A$.
I want to define a function $f$ from $F$ to $A$ that has the following property:
$f(f_i) = R(f_i)$ if $f_i = \arg \min_{f' \in F} f_i(f(f'))$
And
$f(f_i) \in A \backslash \{R(f_i)\}$ otherwise (I haven't decided on the exact value yet)
I was thinking of approaching it in recursive function fashion: start with an initial function $f^0$, use that in the arg mim condition to get $f^1$ then use that to get $f^2$ and so on.
It would be very helpful if I could get the answers to two things:

How do I know the sequence of $f^0, f^1, ....$ would converge? Is the setup of the problem sufficient to guarantee this?

Am I approaching it the right way? Is there any other, good way to deal with my situation?


Thanks!
